# Given 4 points on the perimeter of a circle. Is the center of the circle the only point that is equidistant from these?

Tags: geometry

Given 4 points on the perimeter of a circle. Is the center of the circle the only point that is equidistant from these?

It seems quite likely to me but I don't immediately see a handy proof or intuitive explanation for this. Any help?

Comment: Consider each triple of the points. Each such triple has unique equidistant point. ...

Comment: @Oleg567 Can you prove this? Is this obvious?

Comment: Each triangle $ABC$ has unique escribed circle. Then consider triangle $ABD$. Its (unique!) escribed circle coincides with first one (and, f course, centers coincide). and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is three points.  Say they are $A,B,C$.  the locus of points equidistant from $A,B$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment $\overline {AB}$.  Similarly, the locus of points equidistant from $A,C$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment $\overline {AC}$. The two perpendicular bisectors can't be parallel (as $A,B,C$ can't be collinear) so they intersect in a unique point.

Comment: Interesting, however this is from a problem where given two chords in the same circle, i have constructed a perpendicular bisector on each one and I'm trying to prove that the intersection point is in fact the center of the circle. It is obvious that it is equidistant from the endpoints of the chords (i.e pairwise points on the circle) but does this necessarily mean that it is the center of the circle? (I know the answer is yes but why?)

Comment: Well, by definition the center is equidistant from $A,B,C$.  My intersection is the unique point equidistant from $A,B,C$ by construction, so it must coincide with the center.

Comment: Your solution is rather elegant compared to mine. So given 2 chords; create a third chord by connecting 2 of the endpoints of the given chords. Construct a perpendicular bisector to one of the original chords and the constructed chord and the intersection must then be the center. 

Am I right?

Comment: You can do it  the same way with your two chords.  Say your chords are $\overline {AB}$ and $\overline {CD}$  Let $P$ be the intersection of the two bisectors.  Then $P$ is, by construction, the unique point equidistant to $A,B$ AND equidistant to $C,D$.  But the center has that property as well, so the center must be $P$.

Comment: Oh I see!!! I'm forgetting that a line can only intersect another line once. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just to be sure:  with your two chords, it is possible for the chords to be parallel (that can't happen with my construction).  In that case, your construction degenerates (as the bisectors coincide). But the three point construction works so long as the three points are distinct.